# Jquery only works once per page load - want it work more than once without having to reload page

Tags: javascript, reload, jquery

I want to be able to run this script more than once without reloading the page. Have looked att using Live events, but couldn't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Btw, I'm a noob and I haven't written the script myself.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var $elem = $('#wrapper');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#trigger").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var full_url = this.href;
        var parts = full_url.split("#");
        var trgt = parts[1];
        var target_offset = $("#"+trgt).offset();
        var target_top = target_offset.top;
        $('html, body').delay(2000).animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 2000).delay(250).queue(function() {
            $('#arm').hide();
            $('#arm').toggleClass('arm-down');
        });
    });
    $(function(){
        $('#arm').hide();
        $('#arm').toggleClass('arm-down');
        $('a#trigger').click(function() {
            $('#trigger').addClass('active');
            $('#arm').delay(500).slideToggle().delay(750).queue(function() {
                $('#arm').toggleClass('arm-grab');
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What part of it doesn't work more than once?

Comment: An example, like a jsFiddle, demonstrating what's not working would be helpful.

Comment: Some info on when, besides page load, you want the function to trigger would be nice.

Comment: Sorry. Don't know what jsFiddle is or how it works.

Comment: I don't want it to trigger the function on load, but I want to be able to trigger it more than once per load.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you dont want to set the click handler a bunch of times.  That just leaves the anonoymous function.

Step 1.  !anonymous

Change the anonymous function into a not-anonymous function.

```
function blammo(triggeringEvent)
{
    $('#arm').hide();
    $('#arm').toggleClass('arm-down');
    $('a#trigger').click(function()
    {
        $('#trigger').addClass('active');
        $('#arm').delay(500).slideToggle().delay(750).queue(function()
        {
            $('#arm').toggleClass('arm-grab');
        });
    });
}
```

Step 2. go blammo

Use the not-anonymous function and use the `.on()` jQuery function.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  ... blah ...
  blammo(null); // instead of the anonymous function.

  $(something).on("some event, maybe click", blammo);
}
```

Comment: Easier to write, sure. But there's no functional change from doing it this way.

Comment: If by "no functional change" you mean that the function is now, also, called in response to the event (as setup by the .on()) then I agree.  Otherwise, I must disagree.  The addition of the .on() is new functionality.

Comment: @DwB - Thanks! Total noob, sorry for that. But don't understand step 2. What is blah suppose to include instead? And what about the top part of the script, row 1-14? Thanks again!

Comment: blah is the top part of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Make your anonymous function:

```
function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var full_url = this.href;
        var parts = full_url.split("#");
        var trgt = parts[1];
        var target_offset = $("#"+trgt).offset();
        var target_top = target_offset.top;
        $('html, body').delay(2000).animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 2000).delay(250).queue(function() {
            $('#arm').hide();
            $('#arm').toggleClass('arm-down');
        });
    });
    $(function(){
        $('#arm').hide();
        $('#arm').toggleClass('arm-down');
        $('a#trigger').click(function() {
            $('#trigger').addClass('active');
            $('#arm').delay(500).slideToggle().delay(750).queue(function() {
                $('#arm').toggleClass('arm-grab');
            });
        });
    });
}
```

into a function

`function yourFunction(event)`

which reduces your onLoad to

`$(document).ready(yourFunction)`

now you can call your function whenever you want

```
<script>
//call your function
yourFunction(null)
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but being a total noob, I don't fully follow your fix. Don't know exactly how to make it into a var. Sorry. Could you please be more exact in the steps? Thanks!

Comment: Don't focus on the var part. i made an edit and changed the var keyword to function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any chunk of js to run more than once, put the whole thing in a function, then use `setTimeOut()` in it to call itself.

Comment: But setTimeOut() calls a function every m secs right? I don't the question asks for that?

Comment: No @Ajai, that's setInterval().

Comment: @Abhrani Das: Guess I was a little confused. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea what is going on here, but I'll try anyway :-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#arm').hide().toggleClass('arm-down');
    $('#trigger').on('click', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         var hash = this.href.split("#"),
             target_top = hash[1].offset().top;
         $(this).addClass('active');
         $('#arm').delay(500).slideToggle().delay(750).queue(function() {
             $(this).toggleClass('arm-grab');
         });
         $('html, body').delay(2000).animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 2000).delay(250).queue(function() {
             $('#arm').hide().toggleClass('arm-down');
         });
    });
});
</script>
```