# jquery slideDown only works once

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I am using jquery to make a slide down menu. The code works perfectly the first time the page loads. However, slideDown (the essential part of the click function) doesn't work more than once per menu item. Here is a js fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/74ser/. Any help would be super appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.options').live('click',function() {
            console.log(this);
            var current = this.innerHTML;
            var list = listOfeverythingBut ("options", this);
            console.log(list);
            var stringA = new Array() ;
            var stringUl = new Array();
            for (var i =0; i < list.length; i++){
                var item ="."+list[i].innerHTML+"Menu";
                if ( $(item).length === 1){
                     stringA.push("ul"+ item ); 
                     stringUl.push(item + " a"); 
                }
            }
            stringA = stringA.toString();
            stringUl = stringUl.toString();
            console.log(stringA); 
            console.log(stringUl); 
            var currentItem = "." + current + "Menu";
            console.log(currentItem);
            if ( $(currentItem).length === 1){
                console.log("inOf"); 
                var toSlideDown = 'UL' + currentItem;
                console.log(toSlideDown); 
                console.log($(toSlideDown));
                $(toSlideDown).slideDown('medium');

            }
            else {
                $(".bottom").slideUp(20);
                $('.homeContent').delay(30).fadeIn(30);
            }           
            $(stringUl).slideUp('medium');
             moveDiv(this);
            $(stringA).removeClass('press');

            $('.options').removeClass('largeMenuStyle');
            $(this).addClass('largeMenuStyle');

            //setTimeout( function(){moveDiv(this)}, 2000); 
        });
});
```

note: the essential code is in the `if ( $(currentItem).length === 1)`. I know that it enters the if because it console.logs 'inOf' each time I run the code. Even though it has the correct 'toSlideDown' variable it still doesn't work more than once.

I have already referred to these forum topics, but I haven't found my answer yet.

[Jquery only works once per page load - want it work more than once without having to reload page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434600/jquery-only-works-once-per-page-load-want-it-work-more-than-once-without-havin)

[JQuery click event works only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194728/jquery-click-event-works-only-once)

Comment: put it in a jsfiddle and show your html codes pls

Comment: I edited my comment to include one in the first paragraph

Comment: you are making it waaaay to difficult than it should be... I will take a look at it again

Comment: Just my slideDown code in general is more complex than necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that but your code is very tricky and the HTML structure is very wrong.

Try my hot fix at: http://jsfiddle.net/jvLJs/1/

```
 $(toSlideDown + ' a').show();
 $(toSlideDown).hide().slideDown('medium');
```

Comment: I tried it http://jsfiddle.net/jvLJs/  It makes the menu jerk a bit the second time, but it still isn't functional

Comment: There's an error in console at the line $('.slideshow').cycle({. It seems cycle.js is missing

Comment: Thank you for your response. Cycle.js is for controlling my image slide shows. I didn't include it on my jsfiddle example. But it is on my local copy and I still have the same issues in that local copy. I didn't think it was relavent. Was I wrong?

Comment: Thank you so much for this fix. It works now. I am new at web programming and I am primarily self taught in html, css and jquery. although I have been trained in using javascript. So I am completely open to feedback. What do you mean that my html structure is wrong?

Comment: Glad to help, consider to Accept the answer if it's helpful, and good luck! :)

Comment: you use <ul><a> which is not correct. ul must go along with li. In this case: Ul > li > a. I think somehow you should make the HTML simpler. It's good for you in the future, when you want to modify or add more features

Answer (score -1):

I think this should help although is an old question. I've been having the same problem and I search everywhere to find a solution thinking my problem was in my jQuery file. Then I took a look on my css and found the problem.... basically jQuery animations DON'T WORK if you have declared transition in your css object.
That's it or at least that's what fixed my problem.